# Is there a way to render mako template from a string?

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I need to run render a mako template stored in a string in a database. The code should be like

```
emailtext = render(template_string, {})
```

Is there a way to do so without creating temporary `.mako` file?

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's the first example in the Mako docs: http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage